# How do I get object in JavaScript/HTML from Django by ID?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, ajax

I'm doing a small clinic project using Django. In one page of all html pages I would like to create big buttons in which I have data of specific appointment(id, title, doctor, patient, start hour, end hour). It looks like:

[APPOINTMENT BUTTON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XH4d.png)

There are the fundamental files:

**models.py**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
   id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=defaultTitle)
   description = models.CharField(max_length=480, null=True, blank=True)
   start_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
   end_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True, default=datetime.date.today)
   doctor = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   patient = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='+', blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

**views.py**

```
def doctortoday(request):
   today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
   today_appointments = None
   if request.method == 'GET':
      today_min = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.min)
      today_max = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.date.today(), datetime.time.max)

      try:
         today_appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(doctor=request.user, start_date__range=(today_min, today_max))
      except:
         today_appointments = None

   context = {
       'today': today,
       'appointments': today_appointments
   }
   return render(request, 'doctortoday.html', context)
```

If we click the appointment button then will show popup modal. At the moment there is only QuerySet - {{ appointments }}. [POPUP MODAL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jco5Z.png)

And the my major problem - **how can I display in the popup modal the specific appointment's data without refreshing page?** I just want, if we click the button with Appointment 2 then in the popup modal will be data of the Appointment 2. The same with Appointment 3 etc.

**index.html**

```
<div class="today-appointments">
   {% for appointment in appointments %}
      {% if user.username == appointment.doctor.username %}
          <button id="{{ appointment.id }}" class="btn btn-info" onclick="showProperties(this)">
              <h1>{{ appointment.title }}</h1>
              <p>Doctor: {{ appointment.doctor }}</p>
              <p>Patient: {{ appointment.patient }}</p>
              <p>Date: {{ appointment.start_date|date:'d.m.Y' }}</p>
              <p>Hour: {{ appointment.start_date|date:'H:i' }} - {{ appointment.end_date|date:'H:i' }}</p>
          </button>
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
<div class="popup-properties center">
   <div class="title">
      <p>Properties</p>
   </div>
        <div class="properties">
             <h1>{{ appointments }}</h1>
             <h1></h1> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE TITLE -->
             <p></p> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE DESCRIPTION -->
             <p></p> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE DOCTOR -->
             <p></p> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE PATIENT -->
             <p></p> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE DATE -->
             <p></p> <!-- I WOULD LIKE HERE HOURS -->
             <div class="buttons">
                 <button id="close-properties">Close</button>
                 <button type="submit" id="done-properties">Done</button>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I don't want to use the form tag and csrf_token. I was trying to use AJAX, it looked like that...

I created a new function in views.py:

```
def getAppointmentByID(request):
   id = request.GET.get('id', 1)
   appointment = Appointment.objects.get(id=id)
   return HttpResponse(appointment)
```

And i added a new path in urls.py - **path('getAppointmentByID/', views.getAppointmentByID, name="getAppointmentByID")**. Then I can write link in the browser like it: http://127.0.0.1:8000/account/getAppointmentByID/?id=2 and it shows me the appointment with specific ID typed in link.

Next, on every button I have parameter onclick="showProperties(this)". This Javascript function in that moment looks like:

**showProperties()**

```
function showProperties(info) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("popup-properties")[0].classList.add("active");
        document.getElementById("popup-properties-background").style.display = "block";

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '{{ 'getAppointmentByID/' }}',
            data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: window.CSRF_TOKEN },
            success: function callback(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. In browser's console pops an error - [ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prp71.png).
There must be problem with $.ajax structure.

Is it possible to correct this $.ajax structure? Or maybe exist other way to get the specify appointment without refreshing page?

Peace brothers.

Comment: Why not make a popup *per* appointment? Since Django templates are rendered at the server side, it would result in making an extra query each time you open an appointment, but you already have the data here.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Do you mean add Django templates into popup modal? But how could I display only the appointment from clicked button?

Comment: you can add an id, for example `<div class="popup-properties center" id="popup-app-{{ appointment.pk }}">` for each `appointment` in `appointments`. You should then use an `onclick="showProperties(this, {{ appointment.pk }})"` and slightly modify the javascript to look for a popup with the given primary key.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thanks a lot! I didn't think of it... One more thank you!